# "physical" Windows 7 in VMware

Tags: dual-boot, windows, vmware, virtualization

I'm on an i5-25-something and 8 GB RAM, running ubuntu, 64 bit, 3.11.0-12 generic and want to run my windows 7 partition in a vm workstation. I'm somewhat uncertain as to how to set up the virtual machine.

I have VMware workstation 10.0.1 build-1379776 and the following partition setup:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c1a8b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System   Mount
/dev/sda1   *        2048   125045016    62521484+  83  Linux    /

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x07407b0c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System            Mount
/dev/sdb1            2048     2459647     1228800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT   (windows system_drv (it's a thinkpad))
/dev/sdb2         2459648   197772147    97656250    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT   (windows 7)
/dev/sdb3       197773310   976771071   389498881    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       197773312   976771071   389498880   83  Linux             /home
```

I have created a new VM as root, told it to use sdb2. When I boot the VM, I get a grub rescue line. I suppose from this https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/disks_dualmult_ws.html#wp1046601 and http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html that I somehow need to create an mbr but I've failed at this or rather at using it so far. Maybe someone with a grasp of what I'm doing could digest the tutorial for me and help get this thing running on my partition configuration? I want to not have to reboot to use AutoCAD 2014 and am hoping for decent usability in a VM, albeit I don't know what settings (SCSI? 6 GB Ram for the VM?) would be a good choice nor whether this is even worth the effort and I won't be too unhappy with the VM-Performance to ever use it.

Any comment, suggestion or advice appreciated.

Thanks, Philipp

Comment: Windows, mint, vmware. Where is Ubuntu in this? and no Mint is not ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against this because when you run Windows 7 in the vm it will detect it as a hardware change and may require you to reactivate your license, if the os came with your computer then it's an oem install which means it likely won't allow activation on the vm, additionally if you activate it for the vm successfully then it will detect the host system as a hardware change and may wish to be reactivated again, causing you to enter an endless cycle. Additionally the VM will need Vmware Tools installed, which could cause problems when booting to the host since it will need the drivers you had before installing tools.

As far as your boot problems go, I'm not familiar with the details of the guide you're working on but a simplistic way would be to create a virtual hard drive as the primary drive, and the real-access drive as the secondary. Then using an installation disc, or using the freely available winpe (not recommened) you create a new mbr boot entry for the os on the virtual drives mbr. Before doing anything you should make a backup of your windows installation so you can restore it if things go wrong and ideally have a re-installation disc.

In regards to settings and performance. I've never used cad but it sounds high performance (is it similar to 3D Max?) so you will need to dedicate anything you can to the vm. VMs aren't intended for running high performance applications. However many cores you have on the host dedicate to the vm, this may slightly reduce speed but it will make things run smoother and reduce the chance of freezing. Ram wise you have the right idea, 6gb. I usually run my windows 7 vms on 1gb if I'm just using them to run something light like a web browser (and it's shaky) but when I need to run something more serious I use 4gb or more.

Long story short, you would be better off creating a normal vm and installing windows on it. If you don't have another license/install disc then you can always consider running it in Windows XP. Some versions of Windows 7 qualify for a free download called XP Mode which is actually a Windows XP Professional SP3 install in a Virtual PC VM. According to the AutoCad website Windows XP SP3 is still supported in the 2014 edition of AutoCad, though it won't be in the next version. Since you are using a Mint host there is a slight problem. Virtual PC is only available for Windows hosts, however there are many guides out there for running XP Mode in Vmware or Virtualbox without voiding the vm such as this one: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2014936

The other option would be to if you have access to a windows 7 or 8 installation disc you can install it as a 30day trial, install the program you want, reset the slmgr so the trial starts when the vm boots up next time, create a backup of the vm in a .zip, and then every 30 days just delete the vm and restore it from the backup you made. If you need you can get Windows 7 - Ultimate X86-64 from here: http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso

You may also want to consider running AutoCad in Wine?

Comment: thank you so much for this thorough reply! I understand that I don't really want to run the physical partition in the VM. I can easily install a fresh Windows (students get free licenses by the wagon-load) in a VM and will try out usability.
I would use it for drafting 3D-models to communicate with the production team, so not 3d-max-like. that's also why i can't use an open source 3d tool.

Wine would be perfect. however, winehq gives me the impression it doesn't work with ACAD 2014 and having poked around a little bit I gave up. If you can find a tutorial, I'd be very thankful.